# Simulate position:absolute and higher z-index without using CSS?

Tags: css, html

I've created a code generator which makes it easy for users to embed an image in a website.  This website, however, removes all CSS styling attributes and JavaScript from any code pasted in the input boxes.

This means I have to display my logo beneath or above the generated image on the page.  I want my logo to be displayed on-top the image (preferably in the top-left corner).  Using CSS it would be possible to style this as `position:absolute` and `z-index:2` to generate that effect.  But I can't do that because of the disabled CSS.

Are there any zany ways you can think of to get my logo overlaid on my media without using CSS or JavaScript (so just HTML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without CSS the markup will simply flow. You cannot do it without CSS.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thanks for the answer and confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

In short: No.

You cannot position html elements without css the way you want except by choosing the order from top to bottom (that would be the same as the order in your html structure). So overlaying is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to go a little crazy, you could use PHP's GD Image library to merge your logo over the top. I did something like this for a client last year who wanted an avatar maker that would merge image layers together into one final picture for people to download. Final result was pretty awesome.

http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/gd_library.htm

Comment: I don't know what kind of hosting doesn't allow PHP, but you could go with something like http://www.000webhost.com/. They over crowd their servers, so they aren't real fast. However, they do allow PHP and MySQL use.

Answer (score 0):

Table backgrounds allow you to overlay images on top of each other. The following example offsets the images by 10 pixels:

```
<html><body>
<table background='image_one.png'><tr><td width='10'></td>
<td><img src='image_two.png'></td>
</tr></table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: the only problem is that the website doesn't even accept the <table> tag.  This was a great and sly trick!

Comment: I'm assuming frames are out of the question, too.

Comment: @Jonathan. background is a non-standard attribute.